# Z3 Java API documentation

Tags: java, z3

I have installed the `Z3 API for Java` and I am trying to use it but I can't find any documentation that explains how to use this API.

The only resource I have found so far is the [source code](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8bfbdf1e680d#src/api/java/AlgebraicNum.java) and the [example program](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8bfbdf1e680d#examples/java/JavaExample.java), so I wanted to know if anyone was aware of any other documentation for the `Z3 Java API`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no separate documentation for the Java API (other than the comments in the API itself). Large parts of this API where however automatically translated from the .NET API, so it is virtually the same as that one, as bovoi said. The .NET API is in turn based upon the Python API, so all the class and function names are (almost) the same; in Python there is a default Context object, so in many cases this does not need to be passed as an argument, where in .NET and Java it is an argument. So, apart from the source code of the API and the example program, I would point to the [Z3 Python Tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorial/guide); all the concepts explained therein translate to Java and .NET in a straightforward way.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the API reference at https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacecom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3.html