# Unsigned integers using Java API

Tags: java, z3

I am using the Java API of Z3 and I need to define integer variables which are  natural i.e. their value cannot be negative. How can I define natural data type in z3 using java API?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192058/z3-java-api-documentation-or-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of Java. Pre-Java 8 you have to roll your own type, often by using larger primitives so you can represent the entire range of an unsigned value at the bit-length you require.

This (may) require doing your own two's complement math.

Java 8 has a new Unsigned Integer API, which offer a much easier way of manipulating values in a truly unsigned manner. See the [API docs for Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Comment: Another pre-Java 8 option to consider is also the [Guava's `UnsignedInteger`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInteger.html)